# Record time it takes JUnit tests to run

Tags: java, junit, load-testing

I would like to record how long it takes my JUnit test to run programmatically.  I have a large number of tests in various test classes, and I would like to find out how long each individual test method takes to run.

I can change the inheritance structure or annotate methods differently, but I would like to avoid having to add code within the test method itself and also within the before/after methods which are used to setup test business logic.

Comment: Are you intending to run this in a build tool, for example Maven? Or do you want Eclipse or similar?

Answer (score 13):

You could use the JUnit StopWatch rule and override its methods as provided in the JUnit API documentation and have the time printed to console or log file for each test just by including one line of code in each of your individual test case class.

1. **Create your Customer StopWatch class** (Sample provided)

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException;
   import org.junit.rules.Stopwatch;
   import org.junit.runner.Description;

   public class MyJUnitStopWatch extends Stopwatch{

   private static void logInfo(Description description, String status, long nanos) {
       String testName = description.getMethodName();
       System.out.println(String.format("Test %s %s, spent %d microseconds",
                                 testName, status, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(nanos)));
   }

    @Override
      protected void succeeded(long nanos, Description description) {
          logInfo(description, "succeeded", nanos);
      }

      @Override
      protected void failed(long nanos, Throwable e, Description description) {
          logInfo(description, "failed", nanos);
      }

      @Override
      protected void skipped(long nanos, AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description) {
          logInfo(description, "skipped", nanos);
      }

      @Override
      protected void finished(long nanos, Description description) {
          logInfo(description, "finished", nanos);
      }    
   }
   ```
2. **Have a ParentTestClass created with that line and each of your test class inherit the parent test class:**

   ```
   public class ParentTestCase {


   @Rule
   public MyJUnitStopWatch stopwatch = new MyJUnitStopWatch();

   }
   ```

Child classes inherits parent. No other change in Child classes or before or after methods.

```
public class TestUniqueCharacterString extends ParentTestCase {    

    private String uniqueChars = null;

    @Before
    public void before(){
        uniqueChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop";
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyUniqueCharacterMethod(){


        UniqueCharacteString.doesStringHaveUniqueCharacters(uniqueChars);
    }
```

***Or***

3. **Include this line in each of your Test class**

   ```
   @Rule
   public MyJUnitStopWatch stopwatch = new MyJUnitStopWatch();
   ```

   **Sample Test Class:**

   ```
   import org.junit.After;
   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Rule;
   import org.junit.Test;



   public class TestUniqueCharacterString {    

   @Rule
   public MyJUnitStopWatch stopwatch = new MyJUnitStopWatch();

   private String uniqueChars = null;

   @Before
   public void before(){
       uniqueChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop";
   }

   @Test
   public void testMyUniqueCharacterMethod(){


       UniqueCharacteString.doesStringHaveUniqueCharacters(uniqueChars);
   }

   @Test
   public void testGoodIsUniqueMethod(){
           UniqueCharacteString.isUniqueCharacs(uniqueChars);
   }

   @Test
   public void testGoodIsUniqueMethodWithoutArray(){
       UniqueCharacteString.isUniqueCharsWithoutArray(uniqueChars);
   }

   @After
   public void after(){
       uniqueChars = "";
   }    
    }
   ```

**JUnit API reference:**

http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/Stopwatch.html

**Sample Output**

```
Test testMyUniqueCharacterMethod succeeded, spent 3250 microseconds
Test testMyUniqueCharacterMethod finished, spent 3250 microseconds
Test testGoodIsUniqueMethod succeeded, spent 70 microseconds
Test testGoodIsUniqueMethod finished, spent 70 microseconds
Test testGoodIsUniqueMethodWithoutArray succeeded, spent 54 microseconds
Test testGoodIsUniqueMethodWithoutArray finished, spent 54 microseconds
```

It will also show time for failed and skipped test cases.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use @Before and @After.
A method annotated with @Before or @After runs before or after the test.

```
    @Before
    public void start() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @After
    public void end() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I would like to avoid having to added these to every test class in my project.  Is there a way to add these in one place?

Comment: @oneself Made a parent test case with those two methods, and for every test class you have, extend the parent test case.

Comment: If the test has its own before/after methods, how can I be guaranteed that the timing methods would run immediately before and after the test?  Otherwise, I might also measure the time it takes the test's before/after methods to run.

Comment: @oneself If so, you should build your own timing function. You must trigger and stop the timing function by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a @Rule and instantiate the TestWatcher class.  This is what worked for me.  This is being defined in a class that extends TestCase.

```
public class CompositeWithTeardownDBUnitTest extends DBTestCase {
```

DBTestCase extends TestCase

code snippet in CompositeWithTeardownDBUnitTest

```
@Rule
public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {

    protected void starting(Description description) {
        timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out
                .println("===========================================================================");
        System.out.println("Test: " + description.getMethodName());
        System.out.println("Start Time: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        System.out
                .println("===========================================================================");
    }

    protected void finished(Description description) {
        timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double seconds = (timeEnd-timeStart)/1000.0;
        System.out
        .println("\n===========================================================================");
        System.out
        .println("Test completed - ran in: "+new DecimalFormat("0.000").format(seconds)+" sec");
        System.out
        .println("===========================================================================\n");

    }
};
```

And the JUnit test classes just extend this class CompositeWithTeardownDBUnitTest.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own [`TestWatcher`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) implementation which catches every test method running. Using Guava [`Stopwatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) you can measure time for each test:

```
public class TimeTestWatcher extends TestWatcher {
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();

    protected void starting(Description description) {
        stopwatch.start();
    }

    protected void finished(Description description) {
        stopwatch.stop();

        String testName = description.getMethodName();
        long elapsed = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(String.format("Test %s took %d ms.", testName, elapsed));
    }
};
```

And then add JUnit `@Rule` annotation with your `TimeTestWatcher` for each test class:

```
public class YourTest {

    @Rule
    public TimeTestWatcher watcher = new TimeTestWatcher();

    @Test
    public void testXXX() {}

    @Test
    public void testYYY() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use @Before and @After annotations and note the junit testcase start and endtime. Then finding the difference of two timestamps should give you the testcase execution time. Something like this:

```
 public class Example {

    long startTime;
    long endTime;

    @Before public void recordStartTime() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Test public void testSomething() {
          //test method
    }
    @After public void recordEndAndExecutionTime() {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Last testcase exection time in millisecond : " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to existing answers, you can use a rule for test name along with `Before` and `After` methods to display method name on log. Like this:

```
public class ImageSavingTest {
    @Rule
    public TestName name = new TestName();

    private long start;

    @Before
    public void start() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @After
    public void end() {
        System.out.println("Test " + name.getMethodName() + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    @Test
    public void foobar() {
        // test code here
    }
}
```

Will output:

> Test foobar took 1828 ms

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [JUnit Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) that would record the time between before/after calls. This rule could be used as an instance and/or class rule to get you the time for each individual test method as well as for each test class.