# How to measure test init time JUnit

Tags: java, time, junit

Is there any mechanism to measure how log takes initialization of data for tests in `JUnit`?

I use method `@Before setUp()` that I run before test in order to load some data.

Question is about mechanism in `JUnit`.

If it's possible I would like to avoid using `System.currentTimeMillis();` in each test ;)

Comment: your IDE does not issue any numbers?

Comment: @AndyTurner : OP wants Junit related solution which is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552779/record-time-it-takes-junit-tests-to-run

Comment: @grsdev7 OP appears to be asking specifically about how long it takes to run the `setUp` method, not the overall test. Whilst JUnit coordinates the invocation of that method, there's nothing "JUnit-y" about that method when it's running - it's just a plain old Java method - you can time this method or any other in the same way.